# Better way to organize rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was just wondering if there was a better way to organize these rails routes. Perhaps in a group? I'm unfamiliar with the best practices of something like this.

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'posts#index'
  resources :posts, :except => :destroy
  match '/posts/page/:page' => 'posts#page'
  match '/posts/delete/:id' => 'posts#delete'
  match '/posts/undelete/:id' => 'posts#undelete'
  match '/posts/hide/:id' => 'posts#hide'
  match '/posts/unhide/:id' => 'posts#unhide'
  match '/help' => 'help#index'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can group them in a `collection` block nested within a block on `resources :posts` as follows

```
resources :posts, :except => :destroy do
  collection do
    match 'page/:page'   => 'posts#page'
    match 'delete/:id'   => 'posts#delete'
    match 'undelete/:id' => 'posts#undelete'
    match 'hide/:id'     => 'posts#hide'
    match 'unhide/:id'   => 'posts#unhide'
  end
end
```

These routes aren't very RESTful though. I might suggest something like the following

```
resources :posts, :except => :destroy do
  member do
    get    'page/:page' => 'posts#page'
    delete 'delete'     => 'posts#delete'
    put    'undelete'   => 'posts#undelete'
    put    'hide'       => 'posts#hide'
    put    'unhide'     => 'posts#unhide'
  end
end
```

This creates cleaner routes while still pointing to the same controller/action. You **will** have to modify your application to point to the correct routes a bit differently to support this more accepted behavior though.

```
              GET    /posts/:id/page/:page(.:format)   posts#page
  delete_post DELETE /posts/:id/delete(.:format)       posts#delete
undelete_post PUT    /posts/:id/undelete(.:format)     posts#undelete
    hide_post PUT    /posts/:id/hide(.:format)         posts#hide
  unhide_post PUT    /posts/:id/unhide(.:format)       posts#unhide
        posts GET    /posts(.:format)                  posts#index
              POST   /posts(.:format)                  posts#create
     new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)              posts#new
    edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)         posts#edit
         post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)              posts#show
              PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)              posts#update
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! the latter was exactly what I was looking for. My only question is that you modified the delete action to send an HTTP DELETE, but it doesn't actually delete anything in my tables, it only modifies an is_deleted column in the database. Will that still be okay, or should that be changed to a GET?

Comment: It definitely **should not** be a `GET`. I would personally leave it a `DELETE`, since from a user's perspective the resource *is* removed, but others will argue a `PUT` is more RESTful.